# How can I create a python virtual environment on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

I'm running Windows 10, I'm really new to programming so I'm not really sure what I have to do. I'm able to enter

```
"python -m virtualenv venv"
```

code into the Visual Studio Code terminal, but after that I'm not sure what I have to do. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thank You

- I have finally managed to do it, thank you everyone who helped me.
  :)

Comment: what happened after? what is the error that showed up? if any.

Comment: It says that a virtual environment was created somewhere, however I did not know what to do after this step. I read that i need to activate the virtual environment using the code venv\Scripts\activate, do I put this code into the terminal of the file that I wish to become the virtual environment?

Comment: When i did this, I got "created virtual environment CPython 3.8.5.final.0-32 in 6845ms." What does this mean?

Comment: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows environment, you will need to activate the environment using the following command in powershell:

```
$ .\(new project/directory name)\Scripts\activate
```

Next you can start installing your desired packages like you will normally do using pip.

To cache the required packages, you can using the following command to save the dependencies in to the requirements.txt file.

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To deactivate the environment use the command

`$ deactivate`

If necessary, remove the dependency folder, using (Windows PS)

```
$ rm -r (new project/directory name)
```

After moving the project into a different environment use the following command to reinstall the dependencies after activating the virtual environment.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

** Note for version control usage
Add the virtual environment folder to `.gitignore` file

** If you would like to access the global packages initialize using to following command

```
$ python -m venv (new project/directory name) --system-site-packages
```

Comment: Is the "new project" an actual part of the command in powershell, or is it a reference to some other file? Is directory name is the name of the file I wish to become the virtual environment? Also if using powershell, does virtualenv clash with the use of powershell in any way or can the two used together?

Comment: The (new project/directory name) is the name of your virtual environment, could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Command Palette, and then search for "Python: Select interpreter".

Run this command, and you should be given a list of environments to choose from.

Detailed and complementary instructions are in [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) .

Also note that the environment needs to be activate first on Windows.

Don't hesitate to comment if the above instructions are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in your terminal to "start" the virtualenv:

`venv\Scripts\activate`

Comment: I tried doing this but the system said it cannot identify the path specified.